# What's the reason of using React stateless components anymore?

Tags: reactjs

According to this [website](http://moduscreate.com/react_component_rendering_performance/), the stateless component is the slowest and the PureComponent the fastest.

Is there any reason to not replace all the stateless components with PureComponents in a project ( at least at the moment ) ?

Do you think that in the nearest future will appear a "pure render" version of the stateless component ?

Comment: They serve different needs. You cannot use pure components everywhere.

Comment: The linked article says "I don’t want to say that you should use shouldComponentUpdate all over the place. Adding lots of logic or using it where components rarely output the same HTML code would just add the unnecessary burden. As with everything else, know the power of this lifecycle method and use it wisely."